# Return all id's from a deeply nested Object of arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Assuming I have this deeply nested object

```js
let obj = {
  comp: "el",
  type: "ele",
  children: [
    {
      children: [
        {
          text: "text",
          children: [],
          uid: "-5zIANJjCz-qU0MNcf5E1",
        },
        {
          text:"text",
          children: [],
          uid: "bpeVj4NaD_Io3WP7V0v91"
        }
      ],
      uid: "ZygtUliVsFbFpbmHv5yp9"
    },
    {
      children: [
        {
          text: "text",
          children: [],
          uid: "qmw59v1BVRMEuM8r9VvQp",
        },
        {
          text: "text. ",
          children: [],
          uid: "q-QeWlEnKvVTjD0dPRXCu"
        }
      ],
      uid: "rp_gURLFIgd1n7bn-pRhn"
    },
    {
      children: [
        {
          text: "text",
          children: [],
          uid: "8gIytZ52tq0mqiVAhAJLN",
        },
        {
          text: "text",
          children: [],
          uid: "q-QeeWlEnKvVTjD0dPRXCu"
        }
      ],
      uid: "M3hqA-Rp1wQz60IVdIGUX"
    }
  ],
  uid: "M4JBL9SoOOLo5iQSb5M_P"
};
```

How would I go about getting an array of all uid values?

Currently I am using object scan

https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan

```js
const find = (data, needle) => objectScan([needle], { rtn: "value" })(data);
const allIds = find(obj, "**.uid");
```

This works really well but I am curious how this could be achieved with recursion.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy with a simple helper function that gathers results paired with one that uses that to get the id of every node visited::

```js
const gather = (fn) => (o) => 
  [fn (o), ... (o .children || []) .flatMap (gather (fn))]

const obj = {comp: "el", type: "ele", children: [{children: [{text: "text", children: [], uid: "-5zIANJjCz-qU0MNcf5E1"}, {text: "text", children: [], uid: "bpeVj4NaD_Io3WP7V0v91"}], uid: "ZygtUliVsFbFpbmHv5yp9"}, {children: [{text: "text", children: [], uid: "qmw59v1BVRMEuM8r9VvQp"}, {text: "text. ", children: [], uid: "q-QeWlEnKvVTjD0dPRXCu"}], uid: "rp_gURLFIgd1n7bn-pRhn"}, {children: [{text: "text", children: [], uid: "8gIytZ52tq0mqiVAhAJLN"}, {text: "text", children: [], uid: "q-QeeWlEnKvVTjD0dPRXCu"}], uid: "M3hqA-Rp1wQz60IVdIGUX"}], uid: "M4JBL9SoOOLo5iQSb5M_P"}

console .log (gather (x => x .uid) (obj))

//   or, storing the uid function in a helper: 
// const extractUids = gather (x => x .uid)
// console .log (extractUids (obj))
```

But if you have no other need for the generic solution, you can alternatively inline that helper directly into the function:

```js
const extractUids = (o) => 
  [o .uid, ... (o .children || []) .flatMap (extractUids)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For trees (and graphs without cycles) you can use simple recursion-based strategy as follows:

```
function reduceTree<Item, Acc>(
    next: (item: Item) => Item[],
    reducer: (acc: Acc, item: Item) => Acc
) {
    const step = (acc: Acc, item: Item): Acc => next(item)
        .reduce((_, child) => step(_, child), reducer(acc, item));
    return step;
}

// Test
const allIds = reduceTree(
    (item: TreeItem) => item.children,
    (allIds: string[], item) => [...allIds, item.uid]
)(
    [], obj
);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQhAkpAtsiAD0hABMBnZAJQgQHspSAecsKUAcwBpk4QBPAHzIA3gChkk5AFdgpAFzJW7ENwlSEAC2AAbUhhCL0mHBFwBtALpiAvgG4xY%20iFbI6AIwBWRjNjzIAXlF1elwAB0UAIggdSK51MH4wiCiYiDiQ7T0DRXN1SXEpDSz9CENkPKKiwqqiyGIo%20rAM2qKtXVLyq3jWqVkFZEiAWgBWAC8sAEEAOQApTwBhMaGARwBVAAYAWWmEGBGAUQBGFtabHtaa3qb5SKbT3vbsstzLC97%20qPdkgDVPABZpnAACIAfSwdAAzAB1AAKAHYfhsAG4AThO%20SqNkxkjeOJkciiAC1%20BwwGsdMAfuQAGLuGlhdy4AASyJGSVRkUx50xV2KHRyFXxBWFUhug3u71aT06ryltU%20gxWuAA7iNUcijgAhH5ULYHaRbAAcUFRP2RAEUwg8sfKpHzauK7kQwAA6QZ2tolQXdUWSRWRFZDC0QaE6A4gADSyJ%20qE8wI2pFhVAAGgtpFzetjaniFYTBlAwqCOGsqAAZGlYDikI4geHuEBDMJUTQgTNSHnVfEyn2ih1VJ2Sv3IHsvCq53oEgaRI0cLD8MBEkYAJjAKw2uBWVMmmkmszL0xtRU7l2Hg5dR6qo66E4%20%20cDwcwYYj0dj8cTybTGdF2aqt7695bJCmgrJMQxUGERwqhaYwAGwbFgPykFgADiawpu2ki-hOAZbP8sxamWqIAMp0AA8mRZZ0CMwAWsR7gjFsoKwly9iODA0ggAgYDAHQIDIBgpDSEgxgQEwpi4DwkwIAgggABSYiALqKHJwB4IoEkAJSBMIEm%20kUgnCdAKmIAgijSQgPBqWYGl4NpATCBZYjaXyziuKwEBhIEyByaZ5kyVZ6nIFp-kIDpyBKcQql2aKrqGUgclyaCPAyvZwgeWESUpSUmk8PF0C%20QFyDWbgmmaQ4BkQGA0hQPxGUONiYgAPRNWgECsE4fGuHAOg6FgFDeflokKUU0U2WgvhaeFJWuteUq%20b1-XkIoyicN0xV2eF5iujtPV9RQgVmK6-TWJpI1SOtHieM5DidS4dA6BAro6HQHALft5DlUAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```js
function* get_uid(d){
   yield* ('uid' in d ? [d.uid] : [])
   for (var c of ('children' in d ? d.children : [])){
      yield* get_uid(c)
   }
}
let obj = {'comp': 'el', 'type': 'ele', 'children': [{'children': [{'text': 'text', 'children': [], 'uid': '-5zIANJjCz-qU0MNcf5E1'}, {'text': 'text', 'children': [], 'uid': 'bpeVj4NaD_Io3WP7V0v91'}], 'uid': 'ZygtUliVsFbFpbmHv5yp9'}, {'children': [{'text': 'text', 'children': [], 'uid': 'qmw59v1BVRMEuM8r9VvQp'}, {'text': 'text. ', 'children': [], 'uid': 'q-QeWlEnKvVTjD0dPRXCu'}], 'uid': 'rp_gURLFIgd1n7bn-pRhn'}, {'children': [{'text': 'text', 'children': [], 'uid': '8gIytZ52tq0mqiVAhAJLN'}, {'text': 'text', 'children': [], 'uid': 'q-QeeWlEnKvVTjD0dPRXCu'}], 'uid': 'M3hqA-Rp1wQz60IVdIGUX'}], 'uid': 'M4JBL9SoOOLo5iQSb5M_P'}
var result = [...get_uid(obj)]
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you could trade the expensive `yield*` and intermediate array for `if ("uid" in d) yield d.uid` or `if (d?.uid) yield d.uid`